# the data validation is always return true in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6, cakephp-2.7

the data validation in my User Model always return true. Can anybody tell me why?
The Model: user.php

```
class User extends AppModel {

var $name = "User";

public $validate = array(

    "username" => array(
        "rule" => "notBlank",
        "message" => "Please enter title !",
    ),
    "password" => array(
        "rule" => "notBlank", // tập luật là không rỗng
        "message" => "Please enter info !", // thông báo khi có lỗi
    ));


}
```

**UsersController:**

```
if(($this->request->is('post'))) {

        $this->loadModel('User');
        $this->User->set($this->data);
        echo "</br> vao ".$this->User->validates();
        if($this->User->validates()){
            echo "</br>".$this->User->validates();
            $this->Session->setFlash("Data is avaliable !");

        }else{
            $error = $this->User->validationErrors;
            $this->Session->setFlash("Data is mot avaliable !");
            echo"not validate";
        }
```

But return is alway is true.

I tried to run cakephp 2..7.2 and 2.6.0 but the result is still the same.

Comment: Can you please share the user view code.

Comment: `user.php`, with a lowercase `u`? Really?

Comment: yes, the user view:                                                                                   <form method="post" action="login">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" size="20" /><br />
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password" size="20" /><br />
        <label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Login" />
        <br>
     
    </fieldset>
</form>

Comment: Your view template looks all wrong. Are you not using the FormHelper to generate the form fields? Your two fields should have names more like `data[User][username]` and `data[User][password]`.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 2.x the request/form data is accessed via `$this->request->data` not `$this->data`. So you need to change the line where you set the model's data using `$this->User->set()` to use `$this->request->data`:-

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);
        if ($this->User->validates()){
            $this->Session->setFlash("Data is avaliable !");
        } else{
            $this->Session->setFlash("Data is not avaliable !");
        }
}
```

As long as you're sticking to CakePHP conventions there is no need to load the `User` model in the `UsersController` as it should be auto-loaded. So you can remove `$this->loadModel('User')`.

If you're using the `notBlank` validation rule make sure you are using CakePHP 2.7 as this rule does not exist in earlier versions of Cake. For CakePHP 2.6 use the `notEmpty` rule.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to correct those changes but the result is still the same, always returns true vadidate

Comment: Have you checked what values are getting submitted? Try outputting the value of `$this->request->data` to make sure the fields are present in the posted data.

Comment: please try notEmpty instead of notBlank